# Visual Studio: Why sometimes "Start Without Debugging" much slower than "Start Debugging"?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, debugging

I'm using Visual Studio 2010, C#, WPF. I noticed in some of my projects, "Start Without Debugging" is much more slower than "Start Debugging", maybe 50 times slower.

When "Start Debugging", everything is normal, UI is smooth and responsive. But when "Start Without Debugging", every operation freezes UI for 30~60 seconds.

What are the common causes of this problem? Thanks.

(sorry, I can't upload my projects)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have the problem in Release builds as well?

Are you running antivirus?

Sorry, but I'm not sure we can diagnose your problem without more information.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I don't have problem with release builds. After I read your answer, I disabled my antivirus software (NOD32), and the problem was gone! Thanks! Then I re-enabled NOD32, and tried to reproduce the issue, but I couldn't. This is wired. Why antivirus software (NOD32) greatly impacts the performance of "Start Without Debugging" but not "Start Debugging"?

Comment: I just had this issue again, once I disabled NOD32, everything back to normal. Maybe I should report this issue to NOD32 support.